# 403 Forbidden error in sudo apt-get upgrade ubuntu 17.4

Tags: command-line, package-management, updates

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libqt5test5 amd64 5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5test5_5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: did you try what it tells you to try?

Comment: Have you tried to select another repository server to download from ? THe error you get says "403 Forbidden", that is the server denying you access.

Comment: Yes i tried apt -get update and it dose not work.

Comment: yes i have these :

http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
and i do not know how to add more and which one i should add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday I experienced the same problem with the `bg.` mirror on my 2 computers with Ubuntu. I tried to open `http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com` from the browser and received an error. Then I tried `http://archive.ubuntu.com` and I saw it's working.

So the solution was temporary switching from the local repository `bg.archive.ubuntu.com` to the central repository `archive.ubuntu.com` by editing of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You can do this from the command line by using `sed` command in this way:

```
sudo sed 's/bg.archive.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list -i.bak
```

Later you can restore the original state by the command:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: how you edit it because it written that i don't have permissions

Comment: @AdonNaaman: You should use `sudo` command to gain root access to the file: `sudo nano /path/to/file/`, or `sudo -H gedit /path/to/file`, or use the command from the answer, etc.

Comment: And you can change as well at System Settngs > Software & Updates ("Software Properties" in 16.04)

Comment: i did it and the same result

Comment: @AdonNaaman, can you access `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` from the browser?

Comment: yes i can access the site

Comment: It solved until now after i write this command : sudo apt-get clean

Answer (score -1):

I have gotten that problem before and it was the Firewall/Content Filtering appliance that was blocking access to some of my repo addresses. Not sure if that is a possibility for you.

I whitelisted my linux host on the Firewall/Content Filtering appliance so that it would have unrestricted access outbound.

Comment: and how you solved it

Comment: I whitelisted my linux host on the Firewall/Content Filtering appliance so that it would have unrestricted access outbound

Comment: If you are being blocked by a firewall ALL repos will fail, not just ONE.