# apt-get upgrade: giving 403 Forbidden error for almost all the links

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade

I am a college student and I am getting this error almost for a month. I first thought it was a server error,but I am pretty sure now that it has nothing to do with server as I have tried every server and none of it was profitable.I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for months but this error only presented itself now. Here is my Output for 
**sudo apt-get update** :

```
    Hit:1 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                          
    Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
    Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                              
    Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                   
    Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                           
    Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                           
    Hit:7 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful InRelease                                     
    Get:8 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
    Get:10 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
    Get:11 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
    Get:12 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [397 kB]                                                               
    Get:13 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [454 kB]                                                              
    Get:14 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [169 kB]                                                              
    Get:15 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [234 kB]                                                       
    Get:16 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [52.2 kB]                                                         
    Get:17 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [99.1 kB]                                                         
    Get:18 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [588 kB]                                                          
    Get:19 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [581 kB]                                                           
    Get:20 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [161 kB]                                                          
    Get:21 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [195 kB]                                                   
    Get:22 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [187 kB]                                                      
    Get:23 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [323 kB]                                                      
    Get:24 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,372 B]                                                       
    Get:25 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,524 B]                                                        
    Get:26 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]                                                
    Get:27 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,812 B]                                                
    Get:28 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [168 kB]                                                              
    Get:29 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [218 kB]                                                             
    Get:30 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [84.0 kB]                                                            
    Get:31 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]                                                       
    Get:32 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [101 kB]                                                         
    Get:33 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [99.8 kB]                                                         
    Get:34 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [56.5 kB]                                                        
    Get:35 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.6 kB]                                                 
    Get:36 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [9,088 B]                                                    
    Get:37 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [20.1 kB]                                                    
    Get:38 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,608 B]                                                       
    Get:39 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,440 B]                                                      
    Fetched 4,479 kB in 47s (96.3 kB/s)                                                                                                                                         
    Reading package lists... Done
```

**sudo apt-get upgrade** :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgnome-desktop-3-17 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic netplan.io nodejs nodejs-dev wireshark-common wireshark-qt
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 nplan ubuntu-keyring
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 364 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,120 B of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-keyring all 2018.09.18.1~18.04.0
Ign:2 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 nplan all 0.40.1~18.04.3
Ign:3 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.8.0~20170825.94fa1e38-1ubuntu0.2
Ign:4 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libssh-gcrypt-4 amd64 0.8.0~20170825.94fa1e38-1ubuntu0.2
Err:1 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-keyring all 2018.09.18.1~18.04.0
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
Err:2 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 nplan all 0.40.1~18.04.3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
Err:3 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.8.0~20170825.94fa1e38-1ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
Err:4 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libssh-gcrypt-4 amd64 0.8.0~20170825.94fa1e38-1ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-keyring/ubuntu-keyring_2018.09.18.1~18.04.0_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/nplan_0.40.1~18.04.3_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libssh/libssh-4_0.8.0~20170825.94fa1e38-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libssh/libssh-gcrypt-4_0.8.0~20170825.94fa1e38-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.19.137.75 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

***Sources.list*** :

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

***ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d***

```
$ ls
fossproject-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list              pbek-ubuntu-qownnotes-artful.list.distUpgrade  webupd8team-ubuntu-brackets-bionic.list.save
fossproject-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list.distUpgrade  pbek-ubuntu-qownnotes-artful.list.save         webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list
fossproject-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list.save         vscode.list                                    webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.distUpgrade
google-chrome.list                              vscode.list.save                               webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.save
google-chrome.list.distUpgrade                  webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-bionic.list            wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-zesty.list
google-chrome.list.save                         webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-bionic.list.save       wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-zesty.list.distUpgrade
pbek-ubuntu-qownnotes-artful.list               webupd8team-ubuntu-brackets-bionic.list        wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-zesty.list.save
```

I have tried almost everything but nothing helped. I am not dual booting or anything my normal OS is Ubuntu.Please help me...

Comment: Have you tried to select some other repository ?

Comment: I am using la-mirrors.evowise.com because in the software centre when i chose Best Server this server shows up. But i Have tried Main Server. I dont have a proxy in apt.conf. I also deleted partially downloaded files but nothing's happening.

Comment: How can i select other repos??

Comment: did you update and upgrade your apt, after you edited the list? , if you did it, based from your new `sources.list` the list of `sources.list.d` not like that!!!

Comment: I have tried to update and upgrade after moving the files of sources.list.d to a temporary location,,,but still no updates on the error.

Comment: You are a college student...are you using a school network? If so, looks like you perhaps are not signed in to that network, or are not using that network's required proxy. If so, those would be questions for your network provider (not Ubuntu). If it's a laptop, connect to an off-campus network and see if you get a different result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Forbidden error in sudo apt-get upgrade ubuntu 17.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960442/403-forbidden-error-in-sudo-apt-get-upgrade-ubuntu-17-4)

Comment: No, that method didn't worked for me

Comment: what the output of `cat /etc/hosts && cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: ***cat /etc/hosts*** :

`127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 p3l

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`

Comment: ***cat /etc/resolv.conf*** :
`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: i think that's problem, try to remove your `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` saved and restart your OS!!

Comment: In my case, my infra admin was blocking the mirror host.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix source.list and switch to country's default repository mirror as it is not permitting you to download packages without authentication. You need to edit file /etc/apt/source.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list
```

Replace content with following content

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

After that you will be able to update and upgrade system

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Sorry, not working,Still same errors been showing...

Comment: You should remove other source lists

Comment: Where can i Find them?

Comment: @PearlYadav you still have `Zesty` Repository. change it from `deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main` to `deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main`and remove the 3rd-party repository like as mentioned of @KetanPatel

Comment: I did...Nothing Happened.

Comment: Check and remove every file which is content in /etc/apt/source.list.d/ directory.

Comment: Still..Nothing Changed...

Comment: Can you list content of /etc/apt/source.list and every file of  /etc/apt/source.list.d/ directory ?

Comment: check my question i edited

Comment: remove each and every third party source list sudo rm -f /etc/apt/source.list.d/*

Answer (score 2):

1. Open (or go to) **Software & Updates**
2. Click or expand **Download from**
3. Choose **Other...**
4. Click on **Select Best Server** - you will see "Testing download servers..."
5. After it finishes, click on **Choose server**
6. Close
7. Reload
8. That's it.

Go ahead and run `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score -1):

### [Linux Instructions]

1. [Software Sources][Additional Repositories] Uncheck the repository that was giving the 403 error
2. [Software Sources] When prompted to reload, say OK
3. [Terminal] Verify the issue is gone: `sudo apt update`
4. (Optional) [Terminal] Remove unneeded packages: `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: LM is not Ubuntu, it is not supported here.

Comment: @mikewhatever, my bad. That was just a typo. It's not linux mint. it's ubuntu.